# C: Function do Delete a Node on a Generic Linked List

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I'm having trouble writing a function that will delete a node on a generic linked list.

I have my linked list declared as follow (this is the way my professor wants us to do):

```
typedef enum _STATUS {ERROR,OK} STATUS;
typedef enum _BOOLEAN {FALSE, TRUE} BOOLEAN;

#define MAX_NOME 20


typedef struct _FUNC
{
    char name[MAX_NOME];
    char dept[MAX_NOME];
    BOOLEAN permanent;
} FUNC;


typedef struct _LIST_NODE
{
    void * data;
    struct _LIST_NODE * next;
} LIST_NODE;


typedef LIST_NODE * LIST;

#define DATA(node) ((node)->data)
#define NEXT(node) ((node)->next)
```

I've come with this function to delete all nodes with permanent == FALSE, but it is really not working.

```
void DeleteFuncNotPermanent(LIST *list)
{

    LIST *node = list;

    while ((*list)->next != NULL)
    {
        if(((FUNC*)DATA(*list))->permament == FALSE)
        {
            node = list;
            list = &(NEXT(*node));

            free(DATA(*node));
            free(*node);

        }
        else
        {
            list = NEXT(*list);
        }
    }
}
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In one assignment to list you are assigning a pointer to a pointer, in the other a pointer. One of them is wrong.

Comment: I guess all the macros and unintuitive typedefs are supposed to make everything clearer, but they really make evything more complicated. Also, it would be nice if you could be a bit more specific than "but it is really not working".

Comment: regarding: `_STATUS` and `_BOOLEAN`  a leading underscore followed by a capital letter is 'reserved' for the language implementation

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through the list with a pointer to node pointer, which is a good idea. (Typecasting away the pointer nature of `LIST` is not a good idea, however.) There are several errors in yur code.

To get a pointer to the last element of a list, you do:

```
Node **p = &head;

while (*p) {
    p = &(*p)->next;
}
```

Your respective code, i.e. your function without the deletion stuff, looks like this:

```
    while ((*list)->next != NULL) {
        list = NEXT(*list);
    }
```

You should iterate `while (*list)`. The idea to check `next` probably stems from similar code that uses a node pointer to iterate. When you use a pointer to node pointer, dereferencing that pointer has the same effect as accessing `next`, because that pointer points to the head node at first and to the previous node's `next` member on subsequent iterations.

That's why you must assign the address of `(*list)->next` to `list` when you want to advance the pointer. (The comiler warns you that the pointer types don't match.)

So the "raw" loop should be:

```
    while (*list != NULL) {
        list = &NEXT(*list);
    }
```

Now let's look at deletion. When you have determined that the node should be deleted, you do:

```
    LIST *node = list;

    list = &(NEXT(*node));

    free(DATA(*node));
    free(*node);
```

Here, you do not want to advance the iterator pointer. Instead, you want to update what it points at: You want to skip the current node `*list` by deflecting the pointer that points to the node to the next node or to `NULL`, when that was the last node:

```
    *list = NEXT(*node);
```

When you do that, `list` and `node` will still be the same address, only the contents have changed. (Because `node == list`, `*node` now points at the node after the node you want to delete and you accidentally free that node and its data. Make the temporary pointer a simple node pointer:

```
    LIST node = *list;

    *list = NEXT(node);

    free(DATA(node));
    free(node);
```

Putting it all together:

```
void DeleteFuncNotPermanent(LIST *list, int c)
{
    while (*list)
    {
        if (((FUNC*) DATA(*list))->permament == FALSE)
        {
            LIST node = *list;

            *list = (NEXT(*list));

            free(DATA(node));
            free(node);
        }
        else
        {
            list = &NEXT(*list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really want to thank you for the time you spent writing this comprehensive answer. This didn't help me only in this specific problem but in others as well. I'm sure that this is going to help more people too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to rewrite your delete function. Let me know if it works. The changes are basically related to pointer dereferencing.

```
void DeleteFuncNotPermanent(LIST *list)
{

    LIST *node = list;

    while (list!= NULL)    // change
    {
        if(((FUNC*)(DATA(list)))->permament == FALSE)   // change
        {
            node = list;
            list = NEXT(node);  //change

            free((FUNC*)(DATA(node)));  // change
            free(node);       // change

        }
        else
        {
            list = NEXT(list);    //change
        }
    }
}
```